# Fetch Data by variable with Javascript

Tags: javascript, database, variables, cordova

How would I go about fetching a piece of text that has been outputted via a piece of javascript code and assigning it to the end of the link in the below script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).bind('deviceready', function(){
    var name = $('#name');
    var logo = $('#logo');
    var attacking = $('#attacking');
    var midfield = $('#midfield');
    var defence = $('#defence');
    var rating = $('#rating');
    var url = 'http://79.170.44.147/oftheday.co/fifa/team.php?name=(Piece of text needs to be inputted at the end here, so that the correct data can be fetched)';

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
           $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                  var name1 = ''+item.name+'';
                  name.append(name1);
                  });
           $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                  var logo2 = '<img src="'+item.logo+'" />';
                  logo.append(logo2);
                  });
           $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                  var attacking2 = ''+item.attacking+'';
                  attacking.append(attacking2);
                  });
           $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                  var midfield2 = ''+item.midfield+'';
                  midfield.append(midfield2);
                  });
           $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                  var defence2 = ''+item.defence+'';
                  defence.append(defence2);
                  });
           $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                  var rating2 = ''+item.rating+'';
                  rating.append(rating2);
                  });

           },
        error: function(){
           name.text('There was an error loading the name.');
           logo.text('There was an error loading the logo.');
           attacking.text('There was an error loading the attacking data.');
           midfield.text('There was an error loading the midfield data.');
           defence.text('There was an error loading the defence data.');
           rating.text('There was an error loading the rating data.');
        }
    });
});
});
```

I understand how to do this in PHP it would be something like inserting "'.$name.'" to the end of the link where $name is equal to the outputted content. I don't quite understand how to this here though, the script used to output the previous text is in a separate javascript file too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var url = '.../oftheday.co/fifa/team.php?name='+encodeURIComponent(someVar);`

where does the variable part come from? A dropdown?

If so then

`var url = '.../oftheday.co/fifa/team.php?name='+encodeURIComponent($("#someId").val())`

UPDATE:

`<div onload="onBodyLoad()" id="international"></div>`

would mean

`var url = '.../oftheday.co/fifa/team.php?name='+encodeURIComponent($("#international").text())`

But what is 
onload="onBodyLoad()"
supposed to do? - I do not believe there is such an attribute on a div

Comment: Thank you for your response, it does not however seem to be working, I cannot work out the problem the code is here: http://79.170.44.147/oftheday.co/code.txt

Comment: I have a similiar  question and would to see this  answer as well

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will try out the update when I get the chance. I am using an api for developing an iPhone application, and onBodyLoad() runs a function required for an action via the api.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than constructing the query parameters yourself with string concatenations you would be better off using the `data` parameter of `jQuery.ajax()`. See the docs at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Your ajax call would then look something like this:

```
// Notice that there is no name= in the url
var url = 'http://79.170.44.147/oftheday.co/fifa/team.php';
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: {
        name: $("#international").text()  // this will put the name=... in the query
    }, 
    dataType: 'jsonp',
```